# Express Checkout Paypal Payment Gateway For Woocommerce have issues with Polylang

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, paypal

If we set the language selection URL from the Polylang plugin URL modification at that time PayPal checkout button not working on the cart and checkout page on the website.

[image]

Please once check and let us know if you have any solution to this issue.

Thank you.!

Comment: Looks like the plugin don't support the polylang plugin.

Answer (score 1):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_api_request_url', 'wt_woocommerce_api_request_url', 10, 3);

function wt_woocommerce_api_request_url($api_request_url, $request, $ssl) {

    if ( is_null( $ssl ) ) {
        $scheme = parse_url( home_url(), PHP_URL_SCHEME );
    } elseif ( $ssl ) {
        $scheme = 'https';
    } else {
        $scheme = 'http';
    }

    $lang = 'en';
    if ( function_exists('pll_current_language') ) {
     $lang =  pll_current_language();
    } 

    if ( strstr( get_option( 'permalink_structure' ), '/index.php/' ) ) {
        $api_request_url = trailingslashit( home_url(  $lang .'/index.php/wc-api/' . $request, $scheme ) );
    } elseif ( get_option( 'permalink_structure' ) ) {
        $api_request_url = trailingslashit( home_url(  $lang .'/wc-api/' . $request, $scheme ) );
    } else {
        $api_request_url = add_query_arg( 'wc-api', $request, trailingslashit( home_url( '', $scheme ) ) );
    }

    return esc_url_raw( $api_request_url );
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).